# The thorny issue of duplicate questions (and answers)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As I grow in my participation as a contributor, I'm learning the value of every question here being answered *exactly once*.  Great goal.  But often OPs asking questions, for a number of reasons ranging from laziness to ignorance to (possibly) time constraints, do not have success in finding that their question has already been asked and answered.  So they ask a new question.  And invariably many jump to answer it. Again.

So let's say I see a question and I think, "I'll bet that's been answered." So I do a search -- here or on google -- and find what I think is a perfect match to the OP's needs.  If I mark the question as a duplicate and link to it, there is  no reputation reward.  **In so many other areas SO rewards people for doing the right thing, but this is one activity where the reputation reward is zero and so the proper behavior doesn't appear to be incentivized.**

*What I'd like to see is some small reputation reward for pointing an OP to an asked and answered question that the OP accepts or upvotes*.  It's my opinion that awarding (say) five points for referring to the duplicate would go a long way toward making that behavior much more common.  Quicker and easier than polluting the site with more copies of simple duplicate answers.

Those of you who've been around for years might be thinking, even this question is a duplicate!  But as the site grows, it becomes harder to find duplicates that are easy to recognize as such, particularly for new and low-rep members.  I propose that we **harness the power of the community to help recognize duplicates, and reward that behavior** so OPs can get a already-established answer by awarding some rep incentive for doing that work on behalf the OP.

Thoughts?

Comment: Now where's my reward?

Comment: @Cerbrus At my level I can't see what you did, but I get your humor. ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus There you go:  (Cookies are as good as reputation, right?!)

Comment: I single-handedly closed this question as duplicate. That said, I agree the closing as dupes should be made more appealing... For example, with cookies :D

Comment: @Cerbrus My health prevents me from consuming too many cookies.  There are too many duplicates for cookies to be useful reward.  ;)

Comment: @JLH you'd have to stick with HTTP cookies than... SO should add one more cookie to response per duplicate you found/closed :)

Comment: (As usual I support the goal of the proposal, but so far there were no good suggestion among many attempts that would not at the same time encourage unwelcome behaviors)